# Segmentation fault al recorrer una matriz en C

Tags: c

antes que nada les comento que ya verifique en el foro sobre el error y no encontre la solución ni la explicación de porque se genera este error. Tengo el siguiente código que crea una matriz con los tamaños ingresados por el usuario, el error de `Segmentation fault` solo se presenta cuando la cantidad de filas es igual o mayor a 5, cuando se va a acceder a la posicion `matriz[4][0]` es cuando se produce el error.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <malloc.h>

int filas = 0;
int columnas = 0;
int **matriz = NULL;

int main(){
  inicializarMatriz();
  return 0;
}

void inicializarMatriz(){
  printf("Ingrese el número de filas: ");
  scanf("%d", &filas);
  printf("Ingrese el número de columnas: ");
  scanf("%d", &columnas);
  //Se asigna a la matriz el número de filas ingresado
  matriz = (int**)malloc(filas*sizeof(int));
  //Se asignan a la matriz las columnas por cada fila
  for(int i=0; i < filas; i++){
    matriz[ i ]= (int*)malloc(columnas*sizeof(int));
  }
  //Se solicita llenar la matriz
  for(int f = 0; f < filas; f++){
    for(int c = 0; c < columnas; c++ ){
      //printf("Ingrese el valor para la posición [%d][%d]: ", f, c);
      //scanf("%d",&matriz[f][c]);
      matriz[f][c] = 0;
    }
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
matriz = (int**)malloc(filas*sizeof(int));
```

Esta reserva es, técnicamente, incorrecta. `matriz` es un puntero doble, es decir, que `matriz[i]` apunta a un puntero... y tu estás creando la reserva como si cada elemento apuntase directamente a un entero.

¿Es importante? Puede ser vital para el buen funcionamiento de tu programa:

- En 32 bits, `int` suele ocupar, típicamente, 32 bits, mientras que `int*` suele ocupar 32 bits... en este caso no habría problema.
- En 64 bits, `int` suele ocupar, típicamente, 32 bits, mientras que `int*` suele ocupar 64 bits... en este caso la reserva realizada es justamente la mitad de la requerida.

Para evitar sustos prueba así:

```
matriz = (int**)malloc(filas*sizeof(int*));
//                                     ^ Importante!!!
```

Y, ya puestos, por favor, evita el uso de variables globales salvo que sea un requisito del ejercicio... te ahorrarás muchos sustos.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la colaboración, soluciono el problema, la verdad soy nuevo en c, esto corresponde a un trabajo académico. Tendre en cuenta el uso de variables globales pero por el tipo de trabajo me facilitan la tarea, ya que pasar matrices como argumentos en `c` es más complicado que en `java`.

Comment: @isaac no caigas en esa tentación... lo recomendable es que uses estructuras. Conforme el programa crezca en complejidad la gestión de las variables globales puede volverse un castigo